# Iterating over a composite

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, composite

In the [Head First Design Patterns](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124) book, the authors describe using an iterator to traverse over composite data structures. They provide some [sample code](https://github.com/bethrobson/Head-First-Design-Patterns/tree/master/src/headfirst/designpatterns/composite/menuiterator) which, when executed, prints out a series of menu items stored within the composite. However, if you try to call the iterator more than once, it no longer works as expected and won't produce any results. The following code appears to be causing the problem:

```
public Iterator<MenuComponent> createIterator() {
    if (iterator == null) {
        iterator = new CompositeIterator(menuComponents.iterator());
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

In essence, they are creating a singleton iterator that cannot be reset for future iterations. Unfortunately, simply replacing this logic to return a new instance of the `CompositeIterator` also breaks the algorithm. An [issue](https://github.com/bethrobson/Head-First-Design-Patterns/issues/25) was raised on GitHub several years ago, although is yet to be resolved. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: How about just `return new CompositeIterator(menuComponents.iterator());`?

Comment: @Sweeper the iterator will return duplicate results if you do that.

Comment: Oh I see. How about changing the if condition to `iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the linked issue says in the comments:

```
return iterator; // the `iterator' never resets to null once it's set.
```

We need to reset the `iterator` we are done with it, but not when the iterator still has elements left, because `CompositeIterator` depends on that.

One way to do this is to add another condition on which `iterator` is reset - when the iterator has no more elements:

```
public Iterator<MenuComponent> createIterator() {
    if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator = new CompositeIterator(menuComponents.iterator());
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, thanks! So simple and elegant too. Perhaps you might consider issuing a fix to the Head First repo for extra kudos? It's such a popular book and might benefit others in future. Who knows, your solution might even feature in the next edition!